# Why Is Hands Off Block Local Network Setting Greyed Out?

Tags: firewall

I'm trying to restrict an application's traffic using Hands Off not to be able to connect to servers on the Internet respectively to servers on the LAN. But the when I try to add such a rule, the "Local" and "Local (IPv6)" option is greyed out. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This option seems to be only for outgoing connections, which is too bad. I would also like to be able to restrict some incoming connections to my LAN.